# Joomla 1.5 Database Query example needed

Tags: mysql, joomla, joomla1.5

I have made a query, using `mysql_*` way, that `select`'s some values `from` a `table`, `where` row's `id` is `1`. Then I put all those values in variables so I can echo them in to my form. How can I do the same thing using Joomla's database query way ?

Here is an example of my code that working, using `mysql_*`:

```
<?php // DATABASE QUERY
      $query="SELECT countdown_module, hometeam_header
                FROM jos_gm_nextmatch
               WHERE id = 1";
      $result=mysql_query($query);

      // DATABASE VARIABLES
      $countdown_module = mysql_result($result,$i,"countdown_module"); ?>
      $hometeam_header  = mysql_result($result,$i,"hometeam_header"); ?>

     <form action="" method="post" name="form">
     <input name="countdown_module" value="<?php echo $countdown_module ?>" type="text" />
     <input name="hometeam_header"  value="<?php echo $hometeam_header  ?>" type="text" />
     <input name="submit" type="submit" value="UPDATE" />
     </form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK I found it!!! Here is an example...

```
<?php // DATABASE QUERY
      $db = JFactory::getDBO();
      $query="SELECT countdown_module, hometeam_header
                FROM jos_gm_nextmatch
               WHERE id = 1";
      $db->setQuery($query);
      $rows = $db->loadObjectList();
      $itemrow = $rows[0];

      // DATABASE VARIABLES
      $countdown_module = $itemrow->countdown_module;
      $hometeam_header  = $itemrow->hometeam_header; ?>

     <form action="" method="post" name="form">
     <input name="countdown_module" value="<?php echo $countdown_module ?>" type="text" />
     <input name="hometeam_header"  value="<?php echo $hometeam_header  ?>" type="text" />
     <input name="submit" type="submit" value="UPDATE" />
     </form>
```